# Rails 5 JavaScript pipeline not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to apply a jQuery etalage in my Rails 5 app.

I copied all the assets file to '`app/assets`' folder. I removed the CSS and JavaScripts links from html header file and my 'css' working just fine but JavaScripts not working. JavaScripts only works if I add the link in the body section of my '`html.erb`' file.

My '`html.erb`' file is below: `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pedal House | Single :: w3layouts</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!--webfont-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,900,100,300,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--webfont-->
<!-- dropdown -->


<!--js-->

</head>
<body>
<!--banner-->

<script>  
    $(function () {
      $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        pager: true,
      });
    });
  </script>
<div class="banner-bg banner-sec">  
      <div class="container">
             <div class="header">
                   <div class="logo">
                         <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/logo.png" alt=""/></a>
                   </div>                            
                  <div class="top-nav">                                      
                        <label class="mobile_menu" for="mobile_menu">
                        <span>Menu</span>
                        </label>
                        <input id="mobile_menu" type="checkbox">
                       <ul class="nav">
                          <li class="dropdown1"><a>BIKES</a>
                              <ul class="dropdown2">
                                    <li><a href="bicycles.html">NEW BIKES</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="vpgco.html">VELOCE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="tgbm.html">TREK</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="vpgco.html">PHOENIX</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="tgbm.html">GIANT</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="vpgco.html">GHOST</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="tgbm.html">BINACHI</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="vpgco.html">CORE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="tgbm.html">MUSTANG</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="vpgco.html">OTHERS</a></li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dropdown1"><a href="kids%20item.html">KIDS ITEM</a>

                          </li>
                          <li class="dropdown1"><a href="parts.html">PARTS</a>

                         </li>      
                         <li class="dropdown1"><a href="accessories.html">ACCESSORIES</a>

                         </li>               
                         <li class="dropdown1"><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a>

                         </li>

                      </ul>

                 </div>
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>
             </div>
      </div>                 
</div>
<!--/banner-->
<div class="product">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="ctnt-bar cntnt">
             <div class="content-bar">
                 <div class="single-page">
                     <!--Include the Etalage files-->

                        <script src="assets/jquery.etalage.min.js"></script>
                <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                $('#etalage').etalage({
                    thumb_image_width: 400,
                    thumb_image_height: 400,
                    source_image_width: 800,
                    source_image_height: 1000,
                    show_hint: true,
                    click_callback: function(image_anchor, instance_id){
                        alert('Callback example:\nYou clicked on an image with the anchor: "'+image_anchor+'"\n(in Etalage instance: "'+instance_id+'")');
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
                        <!--//details-product-slider-->
                     <div class="details-left-slider">
                         <div class="grid images_3_of_2">
                          <ul id="etalage">
                            <li>
                                <a href="optionallink.html">
                                    <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="assets/m1.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                                    <img class="etalage_source_image" src="assets/m1.jpg" class="img-responsive" title="" />
                                </a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="details-left-info">
                            <h3>SCOTT SPARK</h3>

                            <h4></h4>
                            <p><label>$</label> 300 </p>

                            <h5>Description  ::</h5>
                            <p class="desc">The first mechanically-propelled, two-wheeled vehicle may have been built by Kirkpatrick MacMillan, a Scottish blacksmith, in 1839, although the claim is often disputed. He is also associated with the first recorded instance of a cycling traffic offense, when a Glasgow newspaper in 1842 reported an accident in which an anonymous "gentleman from Dumfries-shire... bestride a velocipede... of ingenious design" knocked over a little girl in Glasgow and was fined five
                            The word bicycle first appeared in English print in The Daily News in 1868, to describe "Bysicles and trysicles" on the "Champs Elysées and Bois de Boulogne.</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="clearfix"></div>                   
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

     </div>
</div>
<!---->
<div class="footer">
     <div class="container wrap">
        <div class="logo2">
             <p class="copyright">2017 | Developed By <a href="https://www.facebook.com/shofi9x">Hussain</a> & <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ahmed.z.mahin">Zaman</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="ftr-menu">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="bicycles.html">BIKES</a></li>
                 <li><a href="kids%20item.html">KIDS ITEM</a></li>
                 <li><a href="parts.html">PARTS</a></li>
                 <li><a href="accessories.html">ACCESSORIES</a></li>

             </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
</div>
<!---->

</body>
</html>
```

`My 'application.js' file:`

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.easydropdown
//= require jquery.etalage.min
//= require jquery.min
//= require responsiveslides.min
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

`
I'm new with rails and I spent a lot of time to fix this problem. I tried so many ways but none worked. Some expert user please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'` to your Gemfile? In Rails 5 jquery does not come by default.

Comment: Yes I did but still same problem